# Interview question: C program to sort a binary array in O(n)

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I've come up with the following program to do it, but it does not seem to work and goes into infinite loop. Its working is similar to quicksort.

```
int main()
{
 int arr[] = {1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1};
 int N = 18;
 int *front, *last;

 front = arr;
 last = arr + N;
 while(front <= last)
 {
  while( (front < last) && (*front == 0) )
   front++;

  while( (front < last) && (*last == 1) )
   last--;

  if( front < last)
  {
   int temp = *front;
   *front = *last;
   *last = temp;
   front ++;
   last--;
  }
 }
 for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
  printf("%d ",arr[i]);

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: why not just sum up the number of ones, and zeros, and output them in order (pigeon sort)? In your case, 9 zeroes followed by 9 ones, if my count is correct.

Comment: also, what's the question here?

Comment: the first question that comes up into my mind: what do you know about the data to sort ? do they have some properties which would let you simplify your algorithm. (like, they are already sorted, etc...)

Comment: According to Wikipedia, there is no sort algorithm that can perform in O(n) ... except maybe the Simple Pancake Sort ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancake_sorting )

Comment: @pmg: pigeon sort (and the more elaborate radix sort) is O(n). There's no comparison based sort which can perform better than O(n log n) though.

Comment: Thanks all for the suggestion. I can certainly do better by finding sum as suggest by you all. But if asked to sort array of 1's and 2's I think my apporoach will be of help.

Comment: @Zacky112 If you were asked to sort array of 1's and 2's, you could just sum up elements decreased by 1 and reduce to previous solution.

Comment: @Zacky112; your approach will only work with 2 values, if you have three you're out of luck, which is where pigeon(radix) sort will come to the rescue.

Comment: You can even sort an array with 3 distinct (for example: {0, 2, 2, 1,0,0,1} element with O(n) .. Just iterate through the array an move the first kind of element in the beginning, the second in the middle and the third leave in the end.

Comment: are you sure that this was not a trick question? 
i mean why should you sort a binary array? the only thing this accomplishes is that your data is now unreadable or am i missing something?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I see at least two problems in the program:

**Problem 1:**

```
last = arr + N;
```

is incorrect. It should be:

```
last = arr + N - 1;
```

because

```
(arr + 0) points to 0th ele
(arr + 1) points to 1st ele
...
(arr + N -1) points to (N-1)th ele..which is the last element.
```

**Problem2:**
Next your while loop:

```
while(front <= last)
```

is incorrect and should be:

```
while(front < last)
```

In your case when front and last become equal, your loop continues but 
neither front nor last get modified at this point, resulting in infinite loop.

When front and last become equal, it makes no point to continue, your array
would have been sorted by then.

Answer (score 22):

Do you mean the array only has `0`s and `1`s?

Sum all the N elements, then overwrite the array :)

```
int main() {
    int arr[] = {1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1};
    int N = sizeof arr / sizeof *arr; /* 18 */
    int sum = 0;
    int ndx;
    for (ndx=0; ndx<N; ndx++) sum += arr[ndx];
    for (ndx=0; ndx<N-sum; ndx++) arr[ndx] = 0;
    for (ndx=N-sum; ndx<N; ndx++) arr[ndx] = 1;
}
```

Comment: I think you meant to initialize ndx=N-sum in the third loop.

Comment: Thank you Justin, bug squashed

Comment: indeed, this is a special case of [counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort)

Answer (score 5):

The basic idea of your algorithm works well and the implementation can be simplified:

```
int a[] = {1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1};

int *begin = a;
int *end = begin + 17;

while (begin < end) {
   if (*begin == 0)
      begin++;
   else if (*end == 1)
      end--;
   else {
      *begin = 0;
      *end = 1;
   }
}
```

Note that `(begin < end)` is a stronger condition for termination of the loop and in each iteration of the just one action (moving a pointer or swapping values) is taken, simplifying the code and making it easier to understand that the loop will really terminate.

Comment: Why hasn't this got more votes? This solution iterates through the loop just once while the counting approach does twice.

Answer (score 4):

You're making it too hard on yourself! You can do it in O(n) knowing only the size of the array `n` and the sum of the elements `S`. Since a binary array has only two possibilities for each element, knowing how many there are of one element and the total size is good enough.

Once you know that, just output an array containing `S - n` zeroes and `n` ones, in that order. Done!

An alternative approach that doesn't require summing it up first and works in-place is as follows: Place a "write" pointer `w` at index 0 and a "read" pointer `r` at index n-1. Iterate backwards with the read pointer, and each time you encounter a 0, write a "0" at `w` and increment it. When you reach the beginning with `r`, fill the rest of the array with "1" using `w`.

Comment: D'oh. I didn't see roe's comment above when I wrote this answer. Kudos to him for also spotting the easy way out here. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
void my_sort(int* arr, int n){
  int zero = -1;

  for(int i = 0; i < n;i++){
    if(arr[i] == 0){
      zero++; 
      swap(arr[zero],arr[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

keep a pivot for the last zeroth index and keep swapping all numbers from left to right till you reach the end of the array

Answer (score 1):

If you aim at O(n) forget all quicksorts (Θ(nlogn)), bubblesorts etc. No classic sort algorithm achieves O(n) for standard data sets, you must exploit the binary nature of the set.

```
 int arr[] = {1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1};
 int N = 18;
 int i,s=0;
 for(i=0;i<N;i++) s+=(arr[i]==0);
 for(i=0;i<N;i++) arr[i]=!(i<s);
```

Comment: quicksort does not lie in \Theta(n log n)

Comment: @swegi: the normal quicksort doesn't (O(n^2) worst case), but I think his point was that it's greater than O(n), and on average it is O(n log n)

Comment: also, again, radix sort is O(n) which will work as long as you can assign a number to a value (which is trivial for numeric values).

Comment: @roe: do you really believe using Radix sort for this particular task (or pretty much any popular well-known sorting algorithm) is better than applying my "cheat"?

Comment: well, technically, your 'cheat' is a form of radix sort, so yes.. :) or pigeonhole sort if you prefer that. `s` holds the number of zeroes (in your code, `s+=arr[i]` would've held the number of ones), i.e. is the pigeonhole for 0, and N-s is the implicit pigeonhole for ones. And I was referring to your 'no classic algorithm achieves O(n)', which radix sort does. It's very common when you sort any kind of numeric data, such as vectors, points, color values, etc.

Comment: Radix-Sort is only O(n) in very special cases, the general complexity is O(kN) and k can easy be > log N. So in fact for practical purpose you have to kow the data you want so sort _very well_ to be sure it is faster than O(n log(n))

Comment: I just realize the answer I was writing was becoming another version of the answer you already submitted. :) I think the interviewer is looking for the lateral thinking natural and recognize the 'cheat' / 'trick' in this question which is the binary domain :)

Answer (score 1):

Overkill, but you could use Pang Ko's linear time Suffix Array construction algorithm:

http://sites.google.com/site/kopangcn2/software2

That would blow the interviewer's mind :P

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] arr = { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 };

int left = 0;
int right = arr.Length-1;
int first = arr[left];
while (left < right)
{
    if (arr[left] == 0 && arr[right] ==1)
    {
        left++;
        right--;
    }
    else if (arr[left] == 1 && arr[right] == 1)
    {
        right--;
    }
    else if (arr[left] == 0 && arr[right] == 0)
    {
        left++;
    }
    else
    {
        arr[left] = 0;
        arr[right] = 1;
        left++;
        right--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The general solution (if it is not only 0s and 1s) is called "Sorting by Counting". It can always be used if you know that the data is in a certain range. E.g. you want to sort a group of persons by their birthdate, excluding the year.
You just make an array of 367 (leap year) days, and every slot in that array is a (linked)list able to hold your data.
Now you sweep over your data, calculate the "day of year" from the birthday date of the peersons and append them to the approbriated list.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not go into an endless loop on my system:

```
# gcc $CFLAGS -o test test.c
# ./test
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

However the result is wrong. I see 8 times 1, but it should be 9 times one.

As some people pointed out, summing up is a much simpler approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    int i;
    int count;
    int N = 18;
    int arr[] = {1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1};

    /* Sum up all elements */
    i = 0;
    count = 0;
    while (i < N) count += arr[i++];

    /* Overwrite the array */
    i = 0;
    count = N - count;
    while (i < count) arr[i++] = 0;
    while (i < N) arr[i++] = 1;

    /* Print result */
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) printf("%d ",arr[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

apparently the other question was closed... your algorithm works perfectly. what i posted in response to [maddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/253780/maddy) in an apparent [dup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091649/another-interview-question-in-c-closed) of this redirected here by a person who closed it

```
int main()
{
  int v[] = {1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1}; int *a, *b, i, n;
  n = sizeof(v) / sizeof(int);
  for (a = v, b = v + n - 1; a < b; ++a) {
    if (*a) {
      for (; *b; --b) if (a == b) goto end;
      *a = 0; *b-- = 1;
    }
  }
  end: for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) printf("%d%s", v[i], (i==n-1?"\n":",")); return 0;
}
```

moved some lines together to make it fit on the page.... pretty much the same

Answer (score 0):

*Reposting here, as the question where I replied got closed (duplicate of this one).*

I'm sorry about answering this using Python, but it is an exercise I wanted to do. The code is meant to be verbose, to output the steps of the algorithm. Of course, the translation to C is not difficult, as long as you are careful moving the pointer. Cheers!

```
# Put zeros on the left, ones on the right in one pass                                                
a = [1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1]
cl = 0
cr = len(a) - 1
print a

while(True):
    if cl + 1 == cr:
        print 'last pass; adjacent elements'
        if a[cl] == 0:
            print 'a[%d] = 0; leave and exit loop' % (cl)
            print 'final array:'
            print a
            break
        if a[cl] == 1:
            print 'a[%d] = 1; try to swap with a[%d]' % (cl, cr)
            if a[cr] == 1:
                print 'a[%d] = 1 as well; leave and exit loop' % (cr)
                print 'final array:'
                print a
                break
            else:
                print 'a[%d] and a[%d] swapped; leave and exit loop' % (cl, cr)
                a[cl] = 0
                a[cr] = 1
                print 'final array:'
                print a
                break
    if a[cl] == 0:
        print 'a[%d] = 0; leave and move on to a[%d]' % (cl,cl+1)
        cl += 1
        continue
    else:
        print 'a[%d] = 1 move to the right' % (cl)
        while(True):
            if a[cr] == 1:
                print 'a[%d] cannot be moved to a[%d], try a[%d]' % (cl, cr, cr-1)
                cr -= 1
                continue
            else:
                print 'a[%d] swapped with a[%d]' % (cl, cr)
                a[cr] = 1
                a[cl] = 0
                cr -= 1
                cl += 1
                print 'next up: a[%d]; right side blocked up to %d' % (cl,cr)
                break
    if (cl + 1) == cr:
        break
```

Sample output:

```
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
a[0] = 1 move to the right
a[0] cannot be moved to a[26], try a[25]
a[0] swapped with a[25]
next up: a[1]; right side blocked up to 24
a[1] = 0; leave and move on to a[2]
a[2] = 1 move to the right
a[2] cannot be moved to a[24], try a[23]
a[2] swapped with a[23]
next up: a[3]; right side blocked up to 22
a[3] = 0; leave and move on to a[4]
a[4] = 0; leave and move on to a[5]
a[5] = 1 move to the right
a[5] swapped with a[22]
next up: a[6]; right side blocked up to 21
a[6] = 1 move to the right
a[6] cannot be moved to a[21], try a[20]
a[6] cannot be moved to a[20], try a[19]
a[6] swapped with a[19]
next up: a[7]; right side blocked up to 18
a[7] = 1 move to the right
a[7] swapped with a[18]
next up: a[8]; right side blocked up to 17
a[8] = 0; leave and move on to a[9]
a[9] = 0; leave and move on to a[10]
a[10] = 1 move to the right
a[10] cannot be moved to a[17], try a[16]
a[10] cannot be moved to a[16], try a[15]
a[10] swapped with a[15]
next up: a[11]; right side blocked up to 14
a[11] = 0; leave and move on to a[12]
a[12] = 0; leave and move on to a[13]
last pass; adjacent elements
a[13] = 1; try to swap with a[14]
a[13] and a[14] swapped; leave and exit loop
final array:
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a simple answer:)

```
int main()
{
    int a[]={1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1},size=9,end_value,index1,index2=-1;
    end_value=a[size-1];
    for(index1=0;index1 < size-1;index1++)
    {
        if(a[index1]==end_value )
        {
            index2++;
            a[index2]=!a[index2];
            a[index1]=!a[index1];
        }
    }
    index2++;
    a[index2]=!a[index2];
    a[index1]=!a[index1];
}
```

Comment: it's similar to the partition function in quicksort . It's time complexity is O(n) and it's in place too.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a simple binary [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int N = 18, zeros=0, i;
    int arr[] = {1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1}, *ptr, *last;

    ptr = arr;
    last = arr + N - 1;
    while (ptr != last)
    {
        if (!*ptr) zeros++;
        ptr++;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < zeros; i++) arr[i] = 0;
    for (; i < N; i++) arr[i] = 1;

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine. Only a single loop will do the job.

```
int arr[]={0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0};
int lastz=7,i=0,temp,n;
n=9;
while(i<n){
        if(arr[i]==0 && i<lastz){
            lastz=i;
        } else if(arr[i]==1 && lastz<i){
            temp=arr[lastz];
            arr[lastz]=arr[i];
            arr[i]=temp;
            lastz++;
        }
        i++;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the C Implementation which will give the solution in O(n) time.

```
/*
C program to sort a binary array in one pass
Input:  0 1 0 1 1 0
OutPut: 0 0 0 1 1 1
*/

#include<stdio.h>
void segregate0and1(int*, int);

int main()
{
    int a[] = {0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0};
    int array_length = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);

    segregate0and1(a, array_length);

    printf("Array after segregation: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < array_length; i++)
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    printf("\n");    

    return 0;
}

void segregate0and1(int a[], int array_length)
{
    int left = 0, right = array_length-1;

    while (left < right)
    {
        /* Increment left index while we see 0 at left */
        while (a[left] == 0 && left < right)
            left++;

        /* Decrement right index while we see 1 at right */
        while (a[right] == 1 && left < right)
            right--;

        /* If left is smaller than right then there is a 1 at left
          and a 0 at right.  Exchange a[left] and a[right]*/
        if (left < right)
        {
            a[left] = 0;
            a[right] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```